# Windows Batch Script - FOR DO one command at a time

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I made a batch script to find .flv and .mp4 files in subdirectories and create a template .srt file with the same name in that subfolder.

The problem is, I use a FOR DO loop and it seems to spit the commands out too fast for it to be reliable..

Heres the code:

```
for /R %%f in (*.flv) do (
cd  %%~nf
echo.1>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.2>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.00:00:00,000 --^> 00:00:00,000>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~nf".srt
cd..
)
for /R %%f in (*.mp4) do (
cd  %%~nf
echo.1>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.2>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.00:00:00,000 --^> 00:00:00,000>> "%%~nf".srt
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~nf".srt
cd..
)
```

If all goes well.. for ./FILE1/FILE1.mp4 it would make ./FILE1/FILE1.srt that contains:

```
1
00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:03,500
FILE1

2
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,000
FILE1
```

which it does but only for the first few files, then the process seems to go too fast and I get doubles and the wrong titles in the wrong srt files.

It seems like the do ( ... ) loop is spitting out the commands all at the same time. I've even tried to slow it down using PING commands and even tried GOTO commands to break up the work into steps but no luck.

How can I get it to execute one command at a time while still being able to use %%~nf to create and label the .srt files??

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Probably" you are having some kind of problems with nested subdirectories or spaces in directories names and your `cd %~nf` `cd ..` logic. Change to `cd "%~dpf"` to change to the directory where the file resides. Or better, don't change directories and use full paths in every file access.

```
for /R %%f in (*.flv *.mp4) do (
    echo(1
    echo(00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500
    echo(%%~nf
    echo(
    echo(2
    echo(00:00:00,000 --^> 00:00:00,000
    echo(%%~nf
) > "%%~dpnf.srt"
```

Comment: +1, That is exactly how I would do it, except the inner parentheses are not needed. Ditch them, and put the redirection after the outer right parenthesis

Comment: @dbenham: Changed. Initially i was trying to keep the `echo.` sintax in OP question. In this case, for it to work, i had to use the inner parenthesis.

Comment: Thats PERFECT!! Does being right ever get tiring?? =D Thanks to EVERYONE! .. I now have another hurdle to climb, and so I feel it's best posted as a separate question. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims==" %%f in ('dir /s /b /o:gn *.flv *.mp4') DO ( 
echo.1> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.00:00:00,500 --^> 00:00:03,500>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.2>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.00:00:00,000 --^> 00:00:00,000>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
echo.%%~nf>> "%%~dpnf.srt"
)
```